# Getting two separate values from one column

Tags: analytics, tableau-api

As mentioned above, I am currently trying to get two separate values derived from one column.

I have a column named `statusDate`, and I want to know whether if the status have been more than a month. If it's over a month, it will be categorized as `Overdue`, whereas, less than a month will be categorized as `Pending`.

This is what I have tried, however, it only gave me a value, either `Pending` or `Overdue`. However, I want both for comparison reason.

```
IF (DATEDIFF('month', today(), statusDate) > 1)
THEN 'OVERDUE'
ELSEIF (DATEDIFF('month', today(), statusDate) < 1)
THEN 'PENDING'
END
```

Is there anything wrong with my calculated field? Please help, thank you!

I have tried creating two different calculated fields and put both in the row section. However, the result was as following

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I want to create a pie chart to show the percentage of Overdue(Long term) vs Pending(Short term).

Comment: So you want two separate pills for each outcome(Pending & Overdue)? The calculate field seems to be working except it doesn't take into account dates in the past.

Comment: @lampbob yes, i want two separate pills of outcome (Pending & Overdue). I tried on my tableau, all i got was either one of them. Can't get both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I want both for comparison reason.

With your current setup you could easily compare the two values if you drag the calculated field on rows to get the values in separate rows or on colours if you want two differently coloured line graphs.

If you want to colour your pie chart for each state, use the pie as you have it and drag your calculated field to "Colour". This should split the pie as expected.

You could create two separate calculated fields as U.Y. Fried described although this doesn't really give you any additional possibility that you wouldn't already have with your current calculation. 
In the majority of use cases it's a lot easier to compare values if they are in different rows (as you have it, separated by "overdue" and "pending") then comparing values that are in different columns.

Comment: I am trying to create a pie chart to show the percentage of Overdue vs the percentage of Pending. However, I tried the method U.Y. Fried suggested, it didn't work... I have pasted a screenshot for reference purpose.

Comment: You are close. Drag the calculation to colour and it should work. I added it in my answer. Tipp for the next time: it is easier to understand what you do if you take the screenshot including the columns, rows and your dimensions and measures on the left. That gives a lot of context and oftentimes highlights some other mistakes that you might not have thought off.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way how to do it, You could create two fields by creating two calculated fields. the first you should call "overdue" use the following expression;

```
     IF (DATEDIFF('month', today(), statusDate) > 1)
     THEN 'OVERDUE'
     END
```

for the "pending" use;

```
     IF (DATEDIFF('month', today(), statusDate) < 1)
     THEN 'PENDING'
     END
```

IF you'd like to sum them up, return a number, for overdue use;

```
     IF (DATEDIFF('month', today(), statusDate) > 1)
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0
     END
```

do the opposite for pending.

Also you should take in consideration when it equals to exactly a month, use => for greater or equals, and =< for less or equals, it depends on your business logic.

Hope that this helps you!